# ImageMagick montage always chaging from 32 bits to 8 bits

Tags: imagemagick, image-conversion

I am trying to create a montage from a series of 32 bit PNG images. However the result always gets reduced down to 8 bits with no transparency.

Here's an example of one of the source images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj03C.jpg

Here's an example of my command line:

```
montage "%ImgPath%\layer_0.png" "%ImgPath%\layer_1.png" -alpha set -geometry 1500x1500+25+25 "%ImgPath%\lkjdsafd.png"
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Try 
   montage "%ImgPath%\layer_0.png" "%ImgPath%\layer_1.png" -alpha set -geometry 1500x1500+25+25 -depth 32 "%ImgPath%\lkjdsafd.png"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageMagick has some optimizations to reduce the file size when the PNG file is saved to disk. You can prevent this by forcing the format to PNG32. Below is an example of how you could do that:

```
montage "%ImgPath%\layer_0.png" "%ImgPath%\layer_1.png" -alpha set -geometry 1500x1500+25+25 
"png32:%ImgPath%\lkjdsafd.png"
```